# javascript imageslider setinterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 3;
```

I'd like to know why I can't make an `imageslider` this way. I have pictures saved such as `studentbild1`, `studentbild2` and `studentbild3`. How do I get those to show in a `setinterval` like this.

```
window.setInterval(function slideA() {
    var image = document.getElementById('studentbild');
    imagecount = imagecount + 1;
    if(imagecount > total){ imagecount = 1;}
    if(imagecount < 1){ imagecount = total;}
    image.style.backgroundImage = 'url("studentbild" + imagecount + ".jpg")';
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inner double-quotes, replace them with single quotes:

```
image.style.backgroundImage = 'url("studentbild' + imagecount + '.jpg")';
```

to give

```
url("studentbild1.jpg")
```

etc.

```js
var imagecount = 0;
var total = 3;

window.setInterval(function slideA() {
  var image = document.getElementById('studentbild');
  imagecount = imagecount + 1;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  image.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/' + imagecount + '00")';
}, 1000);
```

```css
#studentbild {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="studentbild"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix this (added single quotes near plus signs)

```
image.style.backgroundImage = 'url("studentbild' + imagecount + '.jpg")';
```